# Find Pattern of a Recursive Definition

Tags: recursive-algorithms, integer-sequences

### Premise

I have been playing around for fun with the following recursive relation:

$$
f(1) = \frac{a_1}{2}
$$
$$
f(n+1) = \frac{a_{n+1} - \sum^n_{k=1} f(k) * f(n-k+1)}{2}
$$

Where $a_n$ is a sequence of integers, this generates a new sequence with some properties I have been interested in. The following are the first few terms:

$$
\frac{a_1}{2},\, \frac{a_2}{2} - \frac{a_1^2}{8},\, \frac{a_3}{2} - \frac{a_1*a_2}{4} + \frac{a_1^3}{16},\,…
$$

I had been attempting to remove the recursive relation, but I am not sure where I would even start or if it is even possible.

### Question

I was hoping for some guidance/answer on how (if possible) I might be able to describe the function $f$ without being recursive.

Comment: People don't just go about exploring some seemingly random transforms. People need some ***motivation***; what's yours? To begin with, when is $f(n)$ an _integer_ sequence at all? Certainly not for any integer $a_n$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I can add a **motivation** section, but it is still recreational for I am not a mathematician by training. I am a computer scientist who enjoys mathematics. The main reason is that it represents a _half_ operation for an _addition_ operator which takes a sequence and can produce a group (you can also create a zero for it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me allow to re-index your sequences for convenience, such that the considered recurrence relation becomes
$$
f(n) = \frac{1}{2}\left(a_n - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k)f(n-k)\right), \; f(0) = \frac{a_0}{2}.
$$
The sum corresponds to a (truncated) discrete convolution product. In the continuous case, it would be handled with the help of the Laplace transform, in order to transform it into a standard product, that is why we will use its discrete analog, namely the (unilateral) Z-transform, defined as follows :
$$
F(z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)z^{-n}
$$
A convolution theorem can be straighforwardly deduced from this definition, so that $(f*g)(n) \mapsto F(z) \cdot G(Z)$, hence $F(z) = \frac{1}{2}(A(z) - F(z)^2)$ in the present case, where $A(z)$ is the Z-transform of the sequence $(a_n)_n$, and finally $F(z) = -1 \pm \sqrt{1+A(z)}$, which still has to be inverse-transformed $-$ but the result will depend on $A(z)$.

**N.B. :** it is also possible to use the more common generating function $\tilde{F}(z) = \sum_{n\ge0} f(n)z^n$, but it turns out to be harder to invert in most cases, while retaining the same kind of properties as the unilateral Z-transform, since $\tilde{F}(z) = F(1/z)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am unfamiliar with Z-Transforms. Do you know of where I might learn more in how it would apply to the above sequences? I am looking at sequences $a_n < 2^n$ (which seemed to be important from what I have been able to read so far). If it helps narrow it down even more, the particular sequences that I would like to learn more about are $a_n < \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$.

Comment: After some more digging, I came across [this](https://www.dip.ee.uct.ac.za/~nicolls/lectures/eee4114f/03_ztrans.pdf). Basically, I must first find $A(z)$ by taking the Z-transform of $a_n$. Then plug that into your equation for $F(z)$. From there, I can attempt to find $f(n)$?

Comment: @tkellehe   That's correct, and you'll find $f(n)$ by computing the inverse Z-transform of $F(z)$; however, this last step requires complex integration, that is why I would recommend tu use the generating functions of the considered sequences instead, which is inverted through the $n^\mathrm{th}$ derivative, in the case where you don't feel at ease with this kind of stuff.